# Homeomorphism in metric spaces.

Tags: metric-spaces

Is the circle homeomorphic to the parabola in $\mathbb{R}^2$? 
If yes/no then justify.
I guess the circle is not homeomorphic to the parabola because the circle is compact in $\mathbb{R}^2$ but the parabola is not. Is this a sufficient justification?

Comment: Yes, it is.${}{}$

Comment: Your compactness argument is good. An alternative is to use connectedness: removing a point from the parabola disconnects it but removing a point from the circle does not.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer.